# Access StencilJS component assets in React

Tags: reactjs, stenciljs

I have a Stencil component using its own assets (images). After I build and publish to npm and install the package in my React app, the assets in the Stencil component won't work anymore. React tries to find them in the public folder but they are not there: they are located at node_modules\stencil_project_name\dist.

Question: What's the correct workflow to handle this situation?

Comment: did you find an answer to your question?